# Install git client on windows from command line

Tags: git, installation, window

I want to Install git client on windows from command line.
I have found this https://silentinstallhq.com/git-silent-install-how-to-guide/ and similar suggestions but these parameters are standard options for common setups and not specific for git.
For example I'm looking for a way to set the default editor used by git or enable symbolic links which available when installing with UI.
Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "full UI"? Have you looked at chocolatey?

Comment: The default editor and symbolic links are set by git config. `git config --global core.editor path_to_editor_executable` and `git config --global core.symlinks true`.